# Using regex to search for text that follows a specific word

Tags: python, regex, string

I am searching a string of text which contains dictionaries that look like so:

> soup_string = """{"loadType":"","shiftId":"ROVR-DUMMY-SHIFTID","carbonFriendly":"no","cost":"£2.00","initialSlotPrice":"","timeSlotISO":"2019-06-13T12:00+01:00/13:00+01:00","isSameDayPremium":"false","stopId":"10446315588190612134701380","availability":"full","slotDiscountedByDP":"false","slotId":"1hr-12-13-20190613","time":"12:00pm - 1:00pm","rawSlotPrice":"","slotDiscounted":"false"},
>   {"loadType":"","shiftId":"ROVR-DUMMY-SHIFTID","carbonFriendly":"no","cost":"£2.00","initialSlotPrice":"","timeSlotISO":"2019-06-13T12:30+01:00/13:30+01:00","isSameDayPremium":"false","stopId":"10446315588190612134701380","availability":"available","slotDiscountedByDP":"false","slotId":"1hr-12:30-13:30-20190613","time":"12:30pm - 1:30pm","rawSlotPrice":"","slotDiscounted":"false"}"""

I am looking to return the string which follows each key in the 'dictionaries'.

I have decided an appropriate method is to use Regex expressions. I can return each times and costs using

```py
Costs = re.findall(r"\£[0-9]\.[0-9][0-9]", soup_string)
times = re.findall(r'\"(time)\"\:\"(.{14,16})\"\,', soup_string)
```

Essentially I would like to be able to look for each key in the dictionary, and search for a specific string then return the value.

The end goal is to create a dictionary with the `'Cost', 'Availability' and 'time'`.

Full code:

````py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json

postcode = "L4 0TH"
ASDA_url = "https://groceries.asda.com/api/user/checkpostcode?postcode="+ postcode + "&requestorigin=gi"
ASDA_url2 = "https://groceries.asda.com/api/slot/view?startdate=12%2F06%2F2019&deliveryoption=homedelivery&requestorigin=gi&_="
client = requests.Session()
r = client.get(ASDA_url)
r2 = client.get(ASDA_url2)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r2.text, 'html.parser')
soup_string = str(soup)
soup_dicts = json.loads('[' + soup_string + ']')
keep_keys = ('cost', 'availability', 'time')
filtered = [{k:soup_dict[k] for k in keep_keys} for soup_dict in soup_dicts]```
````

Comment: use json to load it from string to dict then once it is a dict, get all keys and values using .items()

Comment: Could you please give an example as to why this end result dictionary would look like?

Comment: @WillDaSilva The end dictionary would look like
"Cost": "£2.50"
"availability":"available"
"time":"12:30pm - 1:30pm"

Comment: @âńōŋŷXmoůŜ I did do that, but it ends up being an incredibly large dictionary with nested dictionaries and nested lists.

Comment: you have two dictionaries, how will the resulting dictionary look like?

Comment: I have around 150 dictionaries @âńōŋŷXmoůŜ

Comment: you should have shown us your code from the beginning! :D

Comment: I realise that now. Silly of me. Thank you though.

Comment: Hi guys, am I right in thinking this worked the other day but ASDA have updated their website in the meantime and it now requires authentication to get the same data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that you have multiple dictionaries, I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to obtain, but from my understanding this should help:

```py
import json

soup_string = ''' ... ''' # As it is in the question
soup_dicts = json.loads('[' + soup_string + ']')
keep_keys = ('cost', 'availability', 'time')
filtered = [{k:soup_dict[k] for k in keep_keys} for soup_dict in soup_dicts]
```

It treats your string of dictionaries as a list of JSON dictionaries, and uses the `json` module to parse it. Then it filters out everything except the key/value pairs you need. The result is a list of the filtered dictionaries.

Output (i.e. value of `filtered`):

```py
[
    {'cost': '£2.00', 'availability': 'full', 'time': '12:00pm - 1:00pm'},
    {'cost': '£2.00', 'availability': 'available', 'time': '12:30pm - 1:30pm'}
]
```

**EDIT:**

In response to you providing your code, I can see that you're calling `str` on the results from BeautifulSoup. Rather than doing that, you can just process the `client.get()` results directly:

```py
import json
import requests

postcode = "L4 0TH"
ASDA_url = "https://groceries.asda.com/api/user/checkpostcode?postcode="+ postcode + "&requestorigin=gi"
ASDA_url2 = "https://groceries.asda.com/api/slot/view?startdate=12%2F06%2F2019&deliveryoption=homedelivery&requestorigin=gi&_="
client = requests.Session()
r = client.get(ASDA_url)
r2 = client.get(ASDA_url2)
dicts = r2.json()['slotHeader'][0]['slots']
keep_keys = ('cost', 'availability', 'time')
filtered = [{k:d[k] for k in keep_keys} for d in dicts]
```

Comment: So the best way would be to convert it to a json? I have updated the full code I am using.

Comment: @Jack I updated my answer to work with the full code you provided.

Comment: This is perfect. Thank you for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to put your data into a list and create a dictionary with key: data. (see my example below). Then use json to convert it as a dictionary of dictionaries.  Then extract cost, availability and time per dictionary on a loop.

```
import json
soup_string =  """{"data": [{"loadType":"","shiftId":"ROVR-DUMMY-SHIFTID","carbonFriendly":"no","cost":"£2.00","initialSlotPrice":"","timeSlotISO":"2019-06-13T12:00+01:00/13:00+01:00","isSameDayPremium":"false","stopId":"10446315588190612134701380","availability":"full","slotDiscountedByDP":"false","slotId":"1hr-12-13-20190613","time":"12:00pm - 1:00pm","rawSlotPrice":"","slotDiscounted":"false"}, {"loadType":"","shiftId":"ROVR-DUMMY-SHIFTID","carbonFriendly":"no","cost":"£2.00","initialSlotPrice":"","timeSlotISO":"2019-06-13T12:30+01:00/13:30+01:00","isSameDayPremium":"false","stopId":"10446315588190612134701380","availability":"available","slotDiscountedByDP":"false","slotId":"1hr-12:30-13:30-20190613","time":"12:30pm - 1:30pm","rawSlotPrice":"","slotDiscounted":"false"}]}"""
d = json.loads(soup_string)
result = []
cost, avail, time = [], [], []
for data in d['data']:
    tmp = {}
    tmp['Cost'] = data['cost']
    tmp['Availability'] = data['availability']
    tmp['Time'] = data['time']
    result.append(tmp)
result

Output:
[{'Cost': '£2.00', 'Availability': 'full', 'Time': '12:00pm - 1:00pm'},
 {'Cost': '£2.00', 'Availability': 'available', 'Time': '12:30pm - 1:30pm'}]
```

Comment: So you believe the better way to do this would be converting it to a json object? I've also updated my full script